# Multiple SQL Queries with INNER JOIN different parameters?

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I'm not sure what the terminology is for this but I have a mysql query

```
SELECT name, invTypes.typeName, character_skills.trained_skill_level FROM character_skills INNER JOIN character_infos ON character_infos.character_id = character_skills.character_id INNER JOIN invTypes ON character_skills.skill_id = invTypes.typeID WHERE character_skills.active_skill_level <5 AND skill_id = 12203 AND name = 'Mokey PYD';
```

However, there are 2 variables that change and I need to show all of this on a single table.

Those two variables are

```
WHERE character_skills.active_skill_level <5 AND skill_id = 12203
```

For instance

I need to see if the value of `active_skill_level is < 5` for `skill_id 12203` BUT need to also check if `active_skill_level < 4` for `skill_id 12204` and I need these to show on the same table...

Can someone help me out a little bit? Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT name, invTypes.typeName, character_skills.trained_skill_level 
FROM character_skills INNER JOIN character_infos ON character_infos.character_id = character_skills.character_id 
INNER JOIN invTypes ON character_skills.skill_id = invTypes.typeID 
WHERE character_skills.active_skill_level <5 AND skill_id = 12203 AND name = 'Mokey PYD'
union all
SELECT name, invTypes.typeName, character_skills.trained_skill_level 
FROM character_skills INNER JOIN character_infos ON character_infos.character_id = character_skills.character_id 
INNER JOIN invTypes ON character_skills.skill_id = invTypes.typeID 
WHERE character_skills.active_skill_level <4 AND skill_id = 12204 AND name = 'Mokey PYD'
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to union all is an OR  clause

```
SELECT name, invTypes.typeName
  , character_skills.trained_skill_level 
FROM character_skills 
INNER JOIN character_infos ON character_infos.character_id = character_skills.character_id 
INNER JOIN invTypes ON character_skills.skill_id = invTypes.typeID 
WHERE ( character_skills.active_skill_level <5 
AND skill_id = 12203  )  
OR  ( character_skills.active_skill_level <4 
AND skill_id = 12204  ) 
AND name = 'Mokey PYD';
```

Comment: this also might optimize a bit worse then the `UNION ALL` approach depending on the table indexes still +1 as the answer is valid.. I know Oracle database optimizer will optimize and handle `OR` as `UNION ALL` in most cases especially if indexes are involved... As MySQL is owned by Oracle corp i hope MySQL also gets that optimalisation in the future.